# Jersey Deserialize Post Param with an additional Id

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey

I'm just wondering how to modify the following

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createObject(Object object) {
    ...
}
```

to also allow a path parameter?  I was thinking something like

```
@POST
@Path("{server}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createObjectOnServer(@PathParam("server") String url, Object object) {
    ...
}
```

but that either is just wrong or I don't know how the json should be structured.

Comment: Does the first block of code work?

Comment: Yes.  Making calls with JQuery ajax() work correctly.

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an error? The problem could be in many areas. How is the client calling this code? Why are you sending an URL as a path param instead of just using an URL path? And finally, what do you WANT the code to do?

Comment: The servlet can make calls to the same servlet on other nodes without worrying about xss.

Comment: Are you sure you want a PathParam not a PostParam?  A PathParam is a segment of a URL; it has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The second block of code should work, in my project:

```
@POST
@Path("/{mode}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String renderWidget(@PathParam("mode") String mode,RenderingRequest renderingRequest){
    ...
}
```

where 'mode' is a path param and 'RenderingRequest' is a pojo that maps the request body(a json).